# Un-render a template view with hogan.js

Tags: node.js, hogan.js, socketstream

Is there any way to un-render a template with hogan.js. You can just hide it, but that leave's a lot of elements with id's and it can mess up further effects on your site.

I have looked around, but can't find an answer to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hogan.js is a templating language. What means that one can easly render different html markups just using some javascript object. It does not have the purpose of **manipulating the DOM**.

Lets say you got html like this:

```
<body>
  ...stuff...
  <div id="div-1">...stuff...</div>
</body>
```

You could use of course jQuery:

```
$('#div-1').remove();
```

Or if it saves trouble you can use pure javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('div-1');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```